# Drawing a trajectory in javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Not sure where else to ask about this. I'm using a in HTML and would like to draw a trajectory of a projectile starting from the bottom left of a canvas, being shot in an angle, with a certain velocity (like `45degrees` at `10ms`). So far I've mostly seen using the

```
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

ctx.lineTo((180), 180);

ctx.stroke();
```

But that only draws a straight line?

Comment: Add a working code example with what you want (in JSbin for example) and what you expect in more detail

Comment: It's too broad as question...to draw a trajectory you should first of all decide if there is gravity, if you count the mass of the projectile, if there is air resistance. You should use a Physics engine to simplify your life.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is an object with a velocity in both X and Y directions. For each iteration, you'll reduce the velocity for Y due to gravity. For each iteration, you can draw a line, see example below.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = 450;
c.height = 300;

var x = 0;
var y = 300;
var oldX = 0;
var oldY = 300;
var xVel = 10;
var yVel = -20;
var g = 1;


var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
                               x+=xVel;
                               y+=yVel;
                               yVel+=g;
                               ctx.beginPath();
                               ctx.moveTo(oldX,oldY);
                               ctx.lineTo(x,y);
                               ctx.stroke();
                               oldX = x;
                               oldY = y;
  
  if (y>c.height) {clearInterval(myInterval);}
                             },20);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some accurate [x,y] trajectory calculations in Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile

But if you just want your projectile to form an arc to a target you can do it like this:

- Given the starting point (p0) and the target point (p2),
- Calculate a point perpendicular to the midpoint of p0 & p2 at a specified distance (p1),
- Draw a quadratic curve from p0 to p2 with p1 as the curves middle control point.

[image]

If you want to plot points along that quadratic curve you can use De Casteljau's algorithm and then draw your projectile along the plotted points:

```
function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt,endPt,T) {
    var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
    var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y; 
    return( {x:x,y:y} );
}
```

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var p0={x:0,y:ch};
var p2={x:180,y:180};
var distance=25;
var p1;

var nextTime=0;
var delay=1000/60*3;
var pts;
var ptIndex=0;

redraw();

$myslider=$('#myslider');
$myslider.attr({min:0,max:100}).val(distance);
$myslider.on('input change',function(){
  distance=parseInt($(this).val());
  redraw();
});

$('#plot').click(function(){
  pts=plot(p0,p1,p2);
  ptIndex=0;
  requestAnimationFrame(animatePlot);    
});

function animatePlot(time){
  //    if(time<nextTime){requestAnimationFrame(animatePlot);}
  nextTime=time+delay;
  if(ptIndex<pts.length){
    var p=pts[ptIndex];
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p.x,p.y,2,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p2.x,p2.y,4,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillText('['+p2.x+','+p2.y+']',p2.x+10,p2.y);        
    ptIndex++;
    requestAnimationFrame(animatePlot);
  }
}

function plot(p0,p1,p2){
  var pts=[];
  var lastX=p0.x;
  var lastY=p0.y;
  for(var T=0;T<500;T++){
    var p=getQuadraticBezierXYatT(p0,p1,p2,T/500);
    var dx=p.x-lastX;
    var dy=p.y-lastY;
    if(dx*dx+dy*dy>1){
      pts.push({x:p.x,y:p.y});
      lastX=p.x;
      lastY=p.y;
    }
  }
  return(pts)
}

function redraw(){
  p1=pointPerpendicularToMidpoint(p0,p2,distance);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p0.x,p0.y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(p2.x,p2.y,4,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillText('['+p2.x+','+p2.y+']',p2.x+10,p2.y);
}


function pointPerpendicularToMidpoint(p0,p2,distance){
  var dx=p2.x-p0.x;
  var dy=p2.y-p0.y;
  var midpoint={ x:p0.x+dx*0.50, y:p0.y+dy*0.50, };
  var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  var perpendicularPoint={
    x: midpoint.x+distance*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/2),
    y: midpoint.y+distance*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/2)        
  };
  return(perpendicularPoint);
}

function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt,endPt,T) {
  var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
  var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y; 
  return( {x:x,y:y} );
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Change Curve:&nbsp<input id=myslider type=range>
<br>
<button id=plot>Plot the curve</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=250></canvas>
```